# Custom Permalinks with meta value not working. Why?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks

The following code is supposed to work, but it does not (no Plugins activated). In the backend the permalinks are correctly shown for the custom post type, but if called in the frontend an incorrect post is displyed.

It works however, if permalinks are disabled:

```
// register post type
add_action('init','register_item');

function register_item() {


  register_post_type( 'hebamme',
    array(
      'labels' => array(
        'name' => __( 'Hebammen' ), //this name will be used when will will call the investments in our theme
        'singular_name' => __( 'Hebamme' ),
      ),
      'description' => '',
        'public' => true,
      'show_ui' => true,
      'hierarchical' => false, //it means we cannot have parent and sub pages
      'capability_type' => 'post', //will act like a normal post
      'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'hebammen','with_front'=>true), //this is used for rewriting the permalinks
      'query_var' => true,
      'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'revisions','custom-fields'), //the editing regions that will support
      'menu_position' => 5
    )
  );
}

// Permalinks
add_action('init', 'smc_add_rewrite_rules');

function smc_add_rewrite_rules() {
    // Register custom rewrite rules
    global $wp_rewrite;

    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%location%', '([^/]+)', 'location=');
    $wp_rewrite->add_rewrite_tag('%pmcustom%', '([^/]+)', 'pmcustom=');
    $wp_rewrite->add_permastruct('hebamme', '/hebammen/%location%/%pmcustom%/',false);


}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'smc_permalinks', 10, 3);

function smc_permalinks($permalink, $post, $leavename) {

    $no_data = 'na';
    $post_id = $post->ID;
    if($post->post_type != 'hebamme' || empty($permalink) || in_array($post->post_status, array('draft', 'pending', 'auto-draft'))) {
         return $permalink;
    }

    $var1 = get_post_meta($post_id, 'sc_heb_city', true);
    $var1 = sanitize_title($var1);

    if(!$var1) { 
        $var1 = $no_data; 
    }
    return str_replace('%pmcustom%',$post->post_name,str_replace('%location%', $var1, $permalink));
}
```

Comment: `pmcustom` is just postname? why a custom tag and not `postname`? WordPress can't create a main query without some valid query var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Change the rewrite slug in your post type registration to `hebammen/%location%`
2. Delete the whole `smc_add_rewrite_rules` function.
3. Add a filter to [`query_vars`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/query_vars) to register the `location` query var.
4. Change the `smc_permalinks` function to only replace `%location%`, the postname will automatically be inserted.